# Making parent container stretch to width absolutely positioned child and vice versa

Tags: html, css, position, width

I am working with some markup for a drop down menu.

The markup is as follows:

```
<div class="select">
    <a href="#" class="anchor menu-active">
        <label>val1</label><span class="arrow"><label></label></span>
    </a>

    <div class="container menu-visible">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a value="val1" class="item-selected">val1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a value="val2333333333">val2333333333</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first `a` represents the menu item and the `container` div represents a list of submenu items.

- The width of the submenu items are variable as they are generated dynamically.
- The text in anchor is bolded, so in certain cases, the width of the anchor may be bigger than the submenu list.

What needs I need to do: Both the width of the `container` and the `anchor` must be the same. It is possible that the submenu can be wider than the anchor or vice-versa. In addition, the width should not be artificially restricted and should be allowed to expand with the wider content, whether it is the `anchor` or the `container`.

Here's the CSS I have been playing with, but can't seem to get the `anchor` to expand to fit the `container` at all:

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
}

.anchor{
    font-weight: bold;
}

li{
    background: blue;
}

ul{
    display: inline-block;
}

.select{
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MxdQS/

I wish to do this with CSS only, where possible, so no javascript solutions please :)

And a diagram to better demonstrate what I am talking about:
[image]

Some clarification:
If I have 2 containers of different widths and 1 is positioned absolutely, how can I match them up together so that the shorter container will always expand to the width of the longer container?

Could anyone advice as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9CUFh/)** HERE

**CSS**

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width:150px;
}

.anchor{
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li{
    background: blue;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0l
}



.select{
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

check updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QQgA6/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, the width cannot be artificially restricted. For example, if you change one of the list items to be really long, it will extend out of the container.

Comment: what you want that if your text got exceed the width then it will wrap into the li instead of overlap it ....? plz tell me

Comment: The text shouldn't wrap at all. It should just extend onwards.

Comment: There should be no wrapping. For example, if the text in the `li` was `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`, no wrapping should be done and it should appear on just 1 line. Also, I can't have any fixed width. The whole thing should resize depending on the content inside.

Comment: then how you maintain the same width of both .... in your question you mentioned that you want your same width of both containers.... . ????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the question :) If I have 2 containers of different widths, how can I match them up together so that the shorter container will always expand to the width of the longer container?